# Hive couldn't create directory in hdfs and fail to start?

Tags: hadoop, hive

1. I am deploying hive 2.3 in remote mode with a mysql database in another machine as metastore.
2. I am about to finish the whole process and I am checking whether the deployment is working by running bin/hive
3. Then I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't create directory /user/hive/tmp/54de671c-0236-49e2-b967-7c3da8973f3a_resources

4. I know this is set by the property `hive.downloaded.resources.dir` in hive-site.xml. And I set it to be `/user/hive/tmp/${hive.session_id}_resources`.
5. I have create `/user/hive/tmp` in hdfs.
6. I have changed the directory access `$hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /user/hive/tmp`

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I run hive and I got that error as mentioned in point 3

Comment: Dies hive fail even after changing directory permissions?

Comment: Yeah, my problem is still there..

Comment: @SamChan,have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I recently met this problem, too. I have solved it. The key is that "/user/hive/tmp" is not in hdfs, it's in your local folder, and you should create "/user/hive/tmp" in your local folder and change the directory access. Hope to help you solve the problem.

Comment: I created /user/hive/tmp in hdfs,but still get this error

Comment: hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/hive/tmp,but still no success